# <IPython.core.display.HTML object>

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to create graph in PyCharm.

I used the `retentioneering` framework that can be found [here](https://github.com/appintheair/retentioneering-framework/blob/master/examples/event_graph_visualization/user_event_graph_visualization.ipynb).

```
import pandas as pd
from retentioneering import visualization, analysis

data_df = pd.read_csv('datasets/eering.csv')

selected_user_id = 'ad09678628dd1e8c5036974fac434855'
selected_data = data_df[data_df.user_pseudo_id == selected_user_id]
visualization.tree_selectors.print_checkboxes(selected_data, checkbox_id='1', is_checked=True, sep='_')
```

Console output `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`
How to output HTML result in PyCharm Community Edition